# Outlook REST API: Improving Message Syncing Speed

Tags: outlook, office365api, outlook-restapi

There is an optional parameter *odata.maxpagesize* for syncing messages.

This parameter sets the number of messages to be returned in each response and defaults to fifty if not set.

How does *odata.maxpagesize* affect syncing large mailboxes? Think messages in the hundreds of thousands.

If one needed to sync 100,000 messages, how would sync times compare among *odata.maxpagesize* of 100/1000/10000, etc?